# Simulink Desktop Real-Time and Least Mean Square adaptive algorithm

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to implement an LMS-based adaptive audio-cancellation algorithm on the Simulink Desktop Real-Time toolbox.

The physical system is composed of a microphone recording a noise source and another microphone recording the residual noise after the control process (antinoise being injected by a speaker controlled by Simulink).

For the (adaptive) LMS algorithm to work properly I need to be able to work on a sample-by-sample basis, that is at each sampled time instant I need to update the adaptive filter using the synchronised current sample value of both microphones. I realise some delay is inevitable but I was wondering whether it's possible on Simulink Desktop Real-Time to reduce the buffer size of the inputs to one sample and thus work on a sample-by-sample basis.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement the filter on a sample by sample basis.

But you still need a history of input values to perform the actual LMS calculation on.  On a sample by sample basis this would just mean using a simple FIFO buffer.

If you have access to the DSP Toolbox then there is already an [LMS Filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/lmsfilter.html) block that will do this for you.

Comment: I need a slightly modified version of the regular LMS filter so I'll have to implement a custom block. My main concern is that in order to control the noise effectively I have to process the samples in real time, which regular Simulink doesn't ensure (Simulink Desktop Real-Time however should). Thanks for you reply, I'll see if FIFO buffers work.

Comment: Whether Simulink Desktop Real-Time is adequate will depend on the sample rates that you need to achieve.  If you need anything faster than 50-100ms sample rate then it probably won't be good enough for you.